# Operação utilizando campo de outra tabela

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso calcular a quantidade de consumo de um material. E queria buscar o fator multiplicador da unidade de outra tabela, porém o sistema me apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

> "ORA-00937: não é uma função de grupo de grupo simples"

```
SELECT SUM(QT_MOVIMENTACAO)/(SELECT U.VL_FATOR FROM UNI_PRO U WHERE U.CD_PRODUTO = IE.PRODUTO AND 
                             TP_RELATORIO = 'C' )
FROM ITMVTO_ESTOQUE IE
WHERE DH_MVTO_ESTOQUE BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')-31 AND 
                              TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')-1
```

Comment: não dá pra fazer um calculo assim, de um campo (qt_movimentacao)  com um select dentro de outro select. Precisa colocar a outra tabela (UNI_PRO) no `FROM` para ai sim usar (pode fazer um join, cross apply, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece, pois você utilizou campos na query que precisam constar no `group by`, no caso o campo `PRODUTO` da tabela `ITMVTO_ESTOQUE`:

```
WHERE U.CD_PRODUTO = IE.PRODUTO
```

---

Para corrigir isso, basta adicionar o campo `PRODUTO` em seu `group by` após o `where` da query:

```
SELECT SUM(QT_MOVIMENTACAO)/(SELECT U.VL_FATOR FROM UNI_PRO U WHERE U.CD_PRODUTO = IE.PRODUTO AND 
                             TP_RELATORIO = 'C' )
FROM ITMVTO_ESTOQUE IE
WHERE IE.DH_MVTO_ESTOQUE BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')-31 AND 
                              TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')-1
GROUP BY IE.PRODUTO;
```

Porém isso implica que sua query terá como retorno uma linha por produto.

---

Se você deseja apenas uma linha contendo o totalizador, é possível tornar a sua query uma sub-query:

```
SELECT SUM(TOTAL_MOVIMENTO) TOT
  FROM (
          SELECT SUM(QT_MOVIMENTACAO)/(SELECT U.VL_FATOR FROM UNI_PRO U WHERE U.CD_PRODUTO = IE.PRODUTO AND 
                                       TP_RELATORIO = 'C' ) TOTAL_MOVIMENTO
          FROM ITMVTO_ESTOQUE IE
          WHERE IE.DH_MVTO_ESTOQUE BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')-31 AND 
                                        TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')-1
          GROUP BY IE.PRODUTO
        );
```

Com isso você terá apenas uma linha totalizadora com a coluna chamada `TOT`.

---

> Veja um exemplo online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/098ead/11

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre porque no seu `subselect` você está fazendo um filtro pelo produto da tabela principal. E como você não indicou que a consulta deveria ser agrupada pelo código, acaba tendo este problema mesmo.

Pra resolver teria que incluir a coluna `IE.PRODUTO` no `group by`.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT SUM(QT_MOVIMENTACAO)/(SELECT U.VL_FATOR FROM UNI_PRO U WHERE U.CD_PRODUTO = IE.PRODUTO AND TP_RELATORIO = 'C' )
  FROM ITMVTO_ESTOQUE IE
 WHERE DH_MVTO_ESTOQUE BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')-31 AND 
                               TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')-1
 GROUP BY IE.PRODUTO
```

Outra coisa que é possível fazer, é trazer o total utilizando `SUM OVER`, dessa forma não é necessário realizar o agrupamento.

Veja:

```
SELECT SUM(QT_MOVIMENTACAO) OVER(ORDER BY IE.PRODUTO) /(SELECT U.VL_FATOR FROM UNI_PRO U WHERE U.CD_PRODUTO = IE.PRODUTO AND TP_RELATORIO = 'C' )
  FROM ITMVTO_ESTOQUE IE
 WHERE DH_MVTO_ESTOQUE BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')-31 AND 
                               TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')-1
 ORDER BY IE.PRODUTO
```